# Multiple Ckeditor inline editors with custom toolbar options

Tags: ckeditor, inline-editing

I am using CKEditor and have defined a custom toolbar in the config.js file.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
config.uiColor = '#f6f6f6';


config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
[
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },

    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor'] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight'] },
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize'] },
];};
```

however I need to do another custom toolbar to use it at the same page with different options.
I tried to use the code below to configure the 2nd toolbar and it worked, but it stopped all the other editable elements that follows.

```
CKEDITOR.inline("editor1", {   
    extraPlugins: 'sourcedialog',
    toolbar: [
{ name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },
{ name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor'] },
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight'] },
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'] },
{ name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink'] },
{ name: 'insert', items: ['Image'] },
'/',{ name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize', 'Sourcedialog'] }]});
```

I know there is a way to solve this, because here in the official website they have multiple of custom toolbars and all working fine
http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: At the bottom of the mentioned sample there is a section called "Get Sample Source Code". Simply grab the source code and study it, there are helpful comments inside.

Comment: Thank you so much, I totally missed that !